# How to provide support for nested scrolling when using `LazyLayout`

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, nested-scroll, lazylayout

I'm trying to figure out how to make a custom `LazyLayout` work with nested scrolling and in particular supporting `Modifier.pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)` and `Modifier.nestedScroll(TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior().nestedScrollConnection)` modifiers.

Right now, the `LazyLayout` uses `Modifier.pointerInput()` for drag detection, should something else be used?

The current implementation is available [here](https://github.com/oleksandrbalan/minabox/blob/a16fb7293b3db7e952e5995fa58d170a768a32b1/minabox/src/commonMain/kotlin/eu/wewox/minabox/MinaBox.kt#L59) (I'm not the original author of the library, I'm just trying to add nested scroll support to it).